# Problem with understanding the proof of theorem. Let $R$ be a ring with unity satisfy condition $(P_1)$ . Then $N(R)\subseteq Z(R)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a problem with understanding this proof below. Could anyone elaborate on this, please?

**Theorem.** Let $R$ be a ring with unity satisfy condition $(P_1)$:
$P(x,\, y)=\pm Q(x,\, y)$, where $P(x,\, y)=y^{s}[x,\, y]y^{t}$ and $Q(x,\, y)=x^{p}[x^{m},y^{n}]^{r}y^{q}$, $t=0$ for all $x,\, y\in R$ and $m>1, r>0, n\geq0, s\geq0, p\geq0, q\geq0$ are fixed integers. Then $N(R)\subseteq Z(R)$.

Proof. Let $R$ satisfy $P_1$ and let $a\in N(R)$. Then there exists an integer $k\geq l,\,l\geq1$ such that $a^{l}\in Z(R)\;\wedge\; k\geq l,\: l\: minimal$.

I understand that this is trivial for $l=1$. However, I have a problem for $l>1$. It is written that we choose integers like $m_{1}=m_{1}(a^{l-1},y)\geq1,\, r_{1}=r_{1}(a^{l-1},\, y)\geq0,\, n_{1}=n_{1}(a^{l-1},\, y)\geq0,\, s_{1}=s_{1}(a^{l-1},\, y)\geq0,\, p_{1}=p_{1}(a^{l-1},\, y)\geq0,\, q_{1}=q_{1}(a^{l-1},\, y)\geq0$. And the replacing $x$ by $a^{l-1}$ we get $y^{s_{1}}\bigl[a^{l-1},\, y\bigr]=\pm(a^{l-1})^{p_{1}}\bigl[(a^{l-1})^{m_{1}},\, y^{n_{1}}\bigr]^{r_{1}}(a^{l-1})^{q_{1}}=0$

My question is why we choose integers like this and what this symbol exactly means for example $m_{1}=m_{1}(a^{l-1},y)\geq1$ and why the equation above is equal to zero.

Source: http://www.m-hikari.com/ija/ija-2010/ija-25-28-2010/khanIJA25-28-2010-1.pdf

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because of $a\in N(R)$, $a$ is nilpotent, so that some power of it is zero. The last equation is $P(x,y)=Q(x,y)=[\cdots ]\cdots a^{q_1(l-1)}=0$, for $q$ big enough. The notation $m_1(a^{l-1},y)$ should indicate that $m_1$ depends on $a^{l-1}$ and $y$.